# How to force Hangfire to process the queue right now?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, hangfire

I have a queue of fire and forget jobs and my queue is configured to execute every 10 minutes, like this:

```
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) 
};
```

Although the jobs are "fire and forget" i dont want to wait 10 minutes, i want to process the queue right now. How to do this?

Comment: Can you change `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)`? Or use Redis instead? Also see http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval .

Comment: I want to keep the configuration as is, but, sometimes need to force to process the queue right now. I need to use SqlServer

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to keep your code as is (with the 10 minute PollingInterval) but need a mechanism to force jobs to run immediately when required - in which case I think you should be able to use the Hangfire Dashboard UI, where you can see a detailed breakdown of all jobs, as well as retry/trigger now etc.

To install it, just add the Nuget package: `Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization`

and then add the config appropriate to your app type from the following link - it *normally* just works.
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html

**Update - WinForms**

For a WinForms project, I think your best option is still the Dashboard (which you can host in an OWIN server hosted on your localhost from within your application - its easier than you might think)

Here are a few references:

- https://www.codeproject.com/tips/854141/how-to-self-host-web-api-in-asp-net-web-forms-appl
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-owin-hosting-and-self-hosting-in-Asp-Net/ (see last section)

Comment: It is a WinForms project

Comment: I am using the dashboard but just for debug and troubleshooting pourposes, i need to process the queue by custom code.

Comment: I dont know of a way to do that - you could try asking the question on the [Hangfire forum](https://discuss.hangfire.io/)

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I need to do the same thing